# How to do a complicated 2FA authentication in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Ok so this request is a little convoluted. Apologies ahead of time.

Firstly this is what I need:

1. Google signin (using: `.AddGoogle()` and this is working)
2. After signing in initially push user to another page where they must enter a PIN.
3. Verify that PIN against the database on the back-end. If it does not match return user to enter PIN again.
4. Once PIN is verified allow full access to the site (excluding enter PIN page).
5. After X minutes of inactivity (or if the browser is closed) log the user out immediately.

Next, this is what I think I need to do:

1. Use `services.AddAuthentication(...).AddCookie(...).AddGoogle()`.

   So I know that the cookie will have the expiration time embedded into it's contents, but I need some way of also making it expire when the session expires, and keep track of whether or not the PIN has been verified, hence:
2. Create my own middleware that creates a session cookie (if one does not exist) with a random string or number in it.
3. Modify whatever is happening in AddAuthentication with the following behaviour:

   Have ASP.NET write out it's auth cookie with the session cookie's random value encrypted into it.

   Only accept an ASP.NET auth cookie if the cookie's embedded expiration time has not passed AND the auth cookie's embedded session random string matches the session cookie.

   Have ASP.NET auth redirect to the PIN page if no PIN is recorded in the cookie and then forward the request to the appropriate page once the PIN is accepted and recorded back into the auth cookie.

My question is am I right about needing to write my own middleware? Will I need to entirely replace AddAuthentication with my own middleware or can I get what I need by making my own middleware to supplement what AddAuthentication is doing already?

In experimenting one of the things I've had trouble with is if I logout a user in the middleware before authentication (when I detect the session cookie is missing) I can't signal to the authentication mechanism to redirect back to google sign-in, and the user just gets an error and has to refresh.

Additionally, if I am on the right track: How can I create a middleware that will inject a value into the auth ticket before it's created; verify that value; and remove the auth ticket cookie and/or signal to the auth middleware that it should not process the cookie stored in the context's request, and should instead redirect to the google sign-in?

EDIT: So I tried to do some reading on my own. I'm looking at OAuthHandlers and claims, maybe there is some way to utilize this? I'm still investigating but any direction is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As it is generally said: you should not be writing your own authentication.

Since you didn't mention Identity, I'll assume you are not using it. I would recommend using .Net's Identity as it easily covers the problems you have. As of Identity 2.0, external login(Facebook, Twitter, Google) and 2FA functionality are included as a part of this library. This is the defacto authentication system for .Net, and adding it is not too difficult.

The actual implementation of Identity goes beyond the scope of the question so here's a link to help you get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: You can infer from `services.AddAuthentication()` that he's already using identity, but maybe he should've tagged the question as such.  He should take a look at [How SignInManager checks for 2FA requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity#how-signinmanager-checks-for-2fa-requirement).

Comment: Apologies guys, I'm not clear on what is being said in this answer. Are you saying I can have the extra database-backed PIN injected if I were using Identity?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I think I may not have been clear enough. I do not want to use the typical 2FA with an SMS or calculated code, but an extra PIN that is not linked to the google login. This is a requirement for the application. Is there some way to accomplish this through Identity and default authentication mechanisms?